# arp -d address: Operation not permitted linux

Tags: linux, caching, arp

I want to **clear the arp cache** in Linux, and I have tried to do it with
`IP -s -s neigh flush all` And also with `arp -d <specific IP address>`
Both of them does not work...
[image: this is what i get in the terminal..]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check where is your `arp` binary located:

```
$ which arp
/usr/sbin/arp
```

The `sbin` proposes that the binary is intended to be run by **s**uperuser. IT touches things that you don't want to give normal users to touch, as described in manual page:

> **arp -d address**
>
> will delete a ARP table entry. Root or netadmin priveledge is required to do this. The entry is found by IP address. If a hostname is given, it will be resolved  before  looking up the entry in the ARP table.

You need to run it as a `root`, for example using `sudo` should work for you:

```
sudo arp -d <specific IP address>
```